# Internal error at starting android studio after update

Tags: android-studio, exception, nullpointerexception, startup

I'm using ubuntu 20.04

I updated android studio to version 4.1. after that I can't start android studio and shows the following error.

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.a.b.b.d.K.b(K.java:260)
    at com.a.b.b.a.am.c(am.java:297)
    at com.a.b.b.a.am.a(am.java:119)
    at com.a.b.b.a.ai.a(ai.java:56)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.lambda$static$0(JBUIScale.java:76)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicNotNullLazyValue$1.compute(AtomicNotNullLazyValue.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicNotNullLazyValue.getValue(AtomicNotNullLazyValue.java:37)
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.lambda$static$1(JBUIScale.java:155)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.initialize(LazyInitializer.java:113)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$NullableValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:102)
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.lambda$static$2(JBUIScale.java:173)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.initialize(LazyInitializer.java:113)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$NullableValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.LazyInitializer$MutableNotNullValue.get(LazyInitializer.java:102)
    at com.intellij.ui.scale.JBUIScale.scale(JBUIScale.java:297)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.JBInsets.create(JBInsets.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.getRegularPanelInsets(UIUtil.java:1356)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:455)
    ... 9 more

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
```

What should I do to fix this? I tried removing plugins. But it didn't work.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it somehow?

Comment: I have exactly same error during IDE startup. My setup is OpenSuse Tumbleweed, OpenJDK 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting of:

- ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1,
- ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1,
- ~/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

helped me to run AndroidStudio again.